# Using a parent's state in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to develop a counter as a child component that increments every second, or perhaps more frequently in the future, but that is turned on or off by clicking a control component in the parent. I put together a related minimum working example that illustrates something I don't understand.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext} from 'react'                          
                                                                                                     
const TempContext = createContext();                                                                 
const TestChild = () => {                                                                            
  const {masterValue } = useContext(TempContext)                                                     
  const [q, setQ] = useState(0);                                                                     
  console.log('rerender')                                                                            
  useEffect( () => {                                                                                 
    const interval = setInterval( () => {                                                            
      setQ(q+1);                                                                                     
      console.log('observed', masterValue);                                                          
      return () => clearInterval(interval)                                                           
    }, 1000);                                                                                        
  }, [q]);                                                                                           
  return (                                                                                           
  <>                                                                                                 
    {q}. master is {masterValue}                                                                     
  </>                                                                                                
  )                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
const TestParent = () => {                                                                           
  const [masterValue, setMasterValue] = useState(100);                                               
  console.log('master value is', masterValue);                                                       
  return (                                                                                           
    <TempContext.Provider value={{masterValue}}>                                                     
      <div style={{margin: "30vh"}} >                                                                
    <TestChild />                                                                                    
      <div                                                                                           
      style={{width:300, height:300, 'backgroundColor': "lightblue", padding: "3em"}}                
      onClick={ () => {setMasterValue(-1*masterValue)}}>                                             
          Click me                                                                                   
      </div>                                                                                         
    </div>                                                                                           
    </TempContext.Provider>                                                                          
  )                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                    
export default TestParent;
```

I expect this to display a counter that increments up once every second and displays masterValue next to it. I expect that value to change when I click the box and for that change to be reflected in the console log.

Instead, I get no change in the console log except seemingly random intervals (once I've clicked the box at least once) and the counter counts up from zero to `q` every second. **My main issue is figuring out how to use the changed (`onClick`) parent value in the child component**, but help with the weird counter behaviour would also be great! In other words, I want the log statement in `useEffect` to show the same value for `masterValue` that I can observe via the DOM.

Comment: What do you expect when click on the 'Click me' div? Also, I see useEffect have problem, let move `return () => clearInterval(interval)` below interval function (do not write clear effect in function)

Comment: I expect masterValue to change, both in the DOM and in the console.log statement in the effect. Thank you for your help!

Comment: masterValue is not included in the dependencies array of useEffect, so setInterval function will continue to use the initial value of masterValue throughout its execution. You can console.log outside or add masterValue in dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have a sort of delayed infinite loop where the `q` changing causes an additional `setInterval()` to be registered, which changes `q`, which causes an additional `setInterval()` to be registered, etc.

Instead, look at keeping only 1 `setInternal()` "active" at any one time. Also,  use a function value for `setQ()` so that you don't need to depend on the value of `q` in the `useEffect()`.

```js
const {useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext} = React                          
                                                                                                     
const TempContext = createContext();                                                                 
const TestChild = () => {                                                                            
  const {masterValue } = useContext(TempContext)                                                     
  const [q, setQ] = useState(0);                                                                     
  console.log('rerender');
  
  useEffect( () => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setQ(value => value + 1)
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [setQ]);

  return (                        
  <React.Fragment>                                                                                                 
    {q}. master is {masterValue}                                                                     
  </React.Fragment>
  )                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
const TestParent = () => {                                                                           
  const [masterValue, setMasterValue] = useState(100);                                               
  console.log('master value is', masterValue);                                                       
  return (                                                                                           
    <TempContext.Provider value={{masterValue}}>                                                     
      <div style={{margin: "30vh"}} >                                                                
    <TestChild />                                                                                    
      <div                                                                                           
      style={{width:300, height:300, 'backgroundColor': "lightblue", padding: "3em"}}                
      onClick={ () => {setMasterValue(-1*masterValue)}}>                                             
          Click me                                                                                   
      </div>                                                                                         
    </div>                                                                                           
    </TempContext.Provider>                                                                          
  )                                                                                                  
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<TestParent/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: that is *very* helpful thank you - but unfortunately it does not fix the key 'communication' problem - if I put `console.log(masterValue)` after `setQ(value => value + 1)` it always says masterValue is 100 even though I can see it changing in the parent from 100 to -100 and back
`

Comment: Yes, `setInterval()` is only called once when the `setQ` value is created. You'd need to have a dependency on `masterValue` too for the `useEffect()`.

Comment: But that resets the timer every time `masterValue` changes...?

Comment: Yes, indeed it would.

Comment: ...and I don't want that. Any way to avoid that happening?

Comment: Remove the unmounting function, do not have a dependency on `mastervalue` or `console.log()` `masterValue` outside the `useEffect()`.